# question regarding comment section{\usepackage{rotating}}

Tags: errors

My program is showing error at 1.29 line  `section{\usepackage{rotating}}`.
What should i do?
my code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % original 6.25
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\oddsidemargin 20pt    %  Left margin on odd-numbered pages.
\evensidemargin 20pt   %  Note that \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
\topmargin 0pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{Comparative Analysis Of Particle Filtering Techniques}
\lfoot{Ramrao Adik Institute of Technology}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage {graphics}
%\usepackage {algorithm}
%\usepackage {algorithmic}
\usepackage {epsfig}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\section{\usepackage{rotating}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\input{Cover}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{approvalsheet1}\thispagestyle{plain}
\input{coa_examiner}
\input{approvalsheet}
\newpage
\input{acknowledgement}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\input{abstract}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3}
\input{Chapter4}
\input{Chapter5}
\input{bibliography}
\end{document}

%\input{performance}
%\input{obsmanual}
%\input{simulation}
```

Comment: just remove the `\section` command!! (why is that package only in such a command) `\section` is for use in the document to make a section heading.

Comment: Also do not use `epsfig` or `graphics` just use `graphicx` which you have already loaded and don't load `fancyheadings` which has been obsolete for years use `fancyhdr`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to answer this one?

Answer (score 2):

This runs without error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % original 6.25
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\oddsidemargin 20pt    %  Left margin on odd-numbered pages.
\evensidemargin 20pt   %  Note that \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
\topmargin 0pt
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%No \usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{Comparative Analysis Of Particle Filtering Techniques}
\lfoot{Ramrao Adik Institute of Technology}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage {graphics}
%\usepackage {algorithm}
%\usepackage {algorithmic}
%%%%NO! \usepackage {epsfig}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% not in texlive\usepackage{slashbox}
% NO!!:-) \section{\usepackage{rotating}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
% not in texlive \input{Cover}
XXX
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\input{approvalsheet1}\thispagestyle{plain}
%\input{coa_examiner}
%\input{approvalsheet}
\newpage
%\input{acknowledgement}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
%\input{abstract}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\input{Chapter1}
%\input{Chapter2}
%\input{Chapter3}
%\input{Chapter4}
%\input{Chapter5}
%\input{bibliography}
YYY
\end{document}
```